# System of equations to solve this nested radical.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, systems-of-equations, nested-radicals

The nested radical $$1.75793\approx\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}$$ has yet to be given a closed form.

However, nested radicals of the form, $$\sqrt{A+B\sqrt{A+B\sqrt{A+\cdots}}}$$ have the closed form, $$\frac{1}{2}\left(B+\sqrt{B^2+4A}\right).$$ I decided to attempt putting the first nested radical into this form. I know that there are values of $A$ and $B$ that make this possible. For example, we could have $A\approx{0.604235}$, $B=\sqrt{2}$.

We rewrite $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}$$ as $$\sqrt{a}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{a}\sqrt{\frac{2}{b}+\frac{\sqrt{c}}{b}\sqrt{\frac{3}{c}+\frac{\sqrt{d}}{c}\sqrt{\frac{4}{d}+\cdots}}}}$$

Is it possible to find solutions for $A$ and $B$ such that $$A=\frac{1}{a}=\frac{2}{b}=\frac{3}{c}=\frac{4}{d}=\cdots$$ and $$B=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{a}=\frac{\sqrt{c}}{b}=\frac{\sqrt{d}}{c}=\frac{\sqrt{e}}{d}=\cdots$$?

Obviously this system of equations is false and therefore there are no solutions, right? (It would work if instead of using $\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$ we used, for example, $\{1,2,8,128,\dots\}$). But why are there still values of $A$ and $B$ that work. Try plugging $A\approx{2.829018637}$, $B=2$ into $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{A}}\sqrt{A+B\sqrt{A+B\sqrt{A+\cdots}}}.$$ You get the nested radical constant $\approx{1.75793}$, which is what we want. So how can the system of equations be false and there still be solutions?

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ with $f(a) < c < f(b)$, the Intermediate Value Theorem says there is some $x \in (a,b)$ with $f(x) = c$.  You seem to have found that $x$ in the case $f(A) = \sqrt{1/A} \sqrt{A + 2 \sqrt{A + 2\sqrt{A + \ldots}}}$ and $c = 1.75793$.

Comment: I'm sorry. No offense, but isn't that fairly obvious? How exactly does this help answer my question? @Robert Israel

Comment: The point is that there isn't anything special about this.  You have a target number $1.74793$ and a function $f(A)$, and you found a value of $A$ such that $f(A) = 1.74793$.